# Como Comparar Mais de um Dado Entre Duas Planilhas e Somar esses Dados Baseando-se em uma Condição

Tags: microsoft-excel

Possuo duas planilhas, elas possuem basicamente os mesmos dados, mas não são 100% iguais.

Preciso pegar o Id(coluna A) do cliente na planilha1 e verificar na linha onde ele existe na planilha2(coluna A), se o Item(coluna k) desse cliente na planilha1 é igual ao Item(coluna C) na planilha2.

Preciso somar apenas os casos onde na planilha1 a coluna L seja igual ao texto "sucesso".

**Planilha1**

```
A - Id | ... | K - Item | L - STATUS |
   123 | ... |  1234-5  |  Sucesso   | <- Mudou Item
   124 | ... |  1200-0  |  Sucesso   | <- Não mudou Item.
   987 | ... |  0503-7  |  Falha     |
```

---

**Planilha2**

```
A - Id | ... | C - Item |
  123  | ... |  1234-0  | <- Item Original
  124  | ... |  1200-0  | <- Item Original
  987  | ... |  0503-7  |
```

---

**Resultado Esperado:**

Soma: 1.

**OBS:**

- Essa somatória vai em uma outra planilha de resultados.
- As duas planilhas possuem os mesmos Id's, dispostos na mesma ordem.

Não consigo ver uma forma de fazer isso, devido a complexidade de verificar duas planilhas, dois valores e fazer a somatória baseando-se em uma condição.

Comment: Você quer um processo automático (uma macro por exemplo) ou os passos como fazer isso nesta sua planilha?

Comment: Gostaria dos passos de como executar isso para aprender melhor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma jeito de resolver, é criar uma fórmula na sua planilha 1 (ou até mesmo na 2) que retorne 1 ou 0, e com isso, poderá realizar uma soma na sua terceira planilha, veja a fórmula:

```
=SE(E(L2="sucesso"; PROCV(A2;Plan2!$A$2:$C$7;3,1)=K2);1;0)
```

**Desmembrando a função**
Lembre-se, a função será executa em cada linha, então entenda que a referência `L2`, `A2` e `K2` se referem ao seu primeiro item.

```
=SE(
    E(
      L2="sucesso"; --> só vai fazer o procv se for sucesso
      PROCV( --> faz uma busca num intervalo
            A2; --> o valor que está sendo procurado (seu primeiro ID)
            Plan2!$A$2:$C$7; --> é a tabela completa na planilha 2
            3, --> o procv vai retornar o valor da 3º coluna da tabela na plan2
            1 --> a correspondência precisa ser exata
           )=K2); --> se o valor que encontrou na plan2 é igual ao item da plan1
    1; --> coloca o valor 1 na nova coluna "J"
    0) --> coloca o valor 0
```

Após tudo isso, você poderá realizar a soma nesta sua nova coluna "J".
Qualquer nova condição, basta acrescentar um novo parâmetro na função "`E`".

Comment: Dei uma pequena adição de mais conteúdo, para deixar mais claro o que preciso.

Comment: Não existe uma forma de não precisar criar uma nova coluna nessas tabelas e esse resultado ser contabilizado por linha a linha ?
Pq o maior desafio, é realmente fazer que ele vá por exemplo de A1:A1000 sem precisar fazer o incremento manual.

Comment: É perfeitamente possível criar uma função (VBA) que faça todo esse processo automaticamente (você só precisaria alimentá-la informando qual e cada coluna), assim que tiver um tempo tentarei fazer essa função (se ninguém mais a fizer).

Comment: Ocorreu "#N/D", estou tentando ver o motivo.

Comment: Uma vez criada a função, o único custo será corrigir o intervalo da tabela na plan2 (na primeira fórmula). Depois, a alça de preenchimento fará todo o restante.